# How do I write Django related queries using DetailView

Tags: python, django, django-views

How do I write a DetailView in Django, that has other related Queries?

Here is my example:

```
class DistributionDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Distribution
    template_name = 'projects/view_distribution.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DistributionDetailView,
                        self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['weekly_attendance'] = WeeklyAttendance.objects.filter(
            distibution_name=Distribution)
        context['sales_data'] = SalesData.objects.filter(
            distibution_name=Distribution)
        context['theatrical_release'] = TheatricalRelease.objects.filter(
            distibution_name=Distribution)
        return context
```

Comment: U r doing it right ..

Answer (score 0):

`Distribution` is the model class, you can't use it inside `filter()`. In the `get_context_data` method, you can access the current object with `self.object`, for example:

```
context['weekly_attendance'] = WeeklyAttendance.objects.filter(
        distibution_name=self.object)
```

Comment: or just `self.object.weeklyattendance_set.all()`, assuming distribution_name is a FK.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the object with `self.object` in most generic views:

```
class DistributionDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Distribution
    template_name = 'projects/view_distribution.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DistributionDetailView,
                        self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['weekly_attendance'] = WeeklyAttendance.objects.filter(
            distibution=self.object)
        context['sales_data'] = SalesData.objects.filter(
            distibution=self.object)
        context['theatrical_release'] = TheatricalRelease.objects.filter(
            distibution=self.object)
        return context
```